# updating an inner text of xml node after changing the value in datagridview

Tags: c#, xmlnode

i have a small issue...first, i have to read the xml file and extract Arg.2 in a datagridview...then i have to update the value in the datagrid. finally when pressing the update button, i need this value to be written into Arg.2 again and save the xml file with a new name.

i can read the value when extracted and when updated in a message box but i can't see it in the xml file...please let me know what is wrong.

below is the code under button_click:

```
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                XmlDocument Newdoc = new XmlDocument();
                Newdoc.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);

                w = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Arg2"].Value.ToString();
                Newdoc.SelectSingleNode(".//event[@type='2VO']/properties/media[@Arg2]").InnerText = w;
                MessageBox.Show(Newdoc.SelectSingleNode(".//event[@type='2VO']/properties/media[@Arg2]").InnerText);

Newdoc.Save(@"C:\download\updatedxml.xml");
```

strangely, when checking the new updatedxml file, i saw that the value is getting updated in a very strange position...see below (2100 position):

```
<event type="2VO">
          <properties>
            <schedule startType="-ParentEnd" startOffset="00:00:33:00" endType="Duration" endOffset="00:00:22:00" />
            <event title="Pixel VO" reconcileKey="106251137" />
            <mediaStream>
              <cg type="PIXEL CG" />
              <allocation type="ListStream">
                <listStream type="Fixed" listStreamNo="0" />
              </allocation>
            </mediaStream>
            <media RuleCode="2VO" Arg1="TUE" Arg2="1940" Arg3="O1T13810" Arg4="" Arg5="" Arg6="" Arg7="" Arg8="">2100</media>
```

which is not the position needed...is there anything wrong with my Xpath?

Answer (score 0):

do that like this and check validation like **`node exist`** or not check your `XPath`

```
  try 
    {          
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(yourDoc); //load youe xml doc
    doc.SelectSingleNode("your node").InnerText = "new text";//select your node which you want to update
    doc .Save(@"C:\download\updatedxml.xml");
//then show your message box
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
       //catch  exception here
    }
```

then show your message box

Comment: strangely, when checking the new updatedxml file, i saw that the value is getting updated in a very strange position...see below:

Comment: hi tito please update your question with that so that i can understand better

Comment: i did update the main with the xml file as well...strange behavior is observed...have a look. thanks

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the issue...it was an issue with the `Xpath`...so when i modified it to `(.//@Arg.2).innertext`, it worked fine.

Comment: as i told you before  check validation like node exist or not cheers and enjoy mate